# Why would output values from neural network increase / 'explode'?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm training a neural network as part of reinforcement learning using PPO, and when the model is first initialised the outputs look 'normal' like this:

```
[-0.00611657 -0.01238834  0.00284606  0.02600986 -0.00587347 -0.00182077
 -0.00975011]
```

But gradually the outputs increase and after a few hours of training look like this:

```
[-3119.771    1075.3921    513.0797  -3039.5288  -2695.9114    388.93564
 -3112.1418 ]
```

The rewards from the environment is always between -5 to +5 and they're normalized:

```
rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / torch.max(rewards.std(), torch.tensor(1e-5))
```

I'm thinking that points to an error somewhere?  Any ideas of what could cause outputs to 'explode' like this?

Model architecture is as follows:

```
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=174, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (1): ReLU()
  (2): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (3): ReLU()
  (4): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (5): ReLU()
  (6): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (7): ReLU()
  (8): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (9): ReLU()
  (10): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=500, bias=True)
  (11): ReLU()
  (12): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=7, bias=True)
)
```

Comment: It should be caused by gradient explosion.

Comment: You were right, Kris.  Found a large bug in my code.